# How to perform operations on pyspark dataframe in a function which needs to run in parallel?

Tags: pandas, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a function created in an Azure Databricks notebook which has a basic transformation (for this question I simplified my function) like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Notebook').getOrCreate()
calculation(account, data):

   data_account = spark.createDataFrame(data)

   return data_account
```

In this function, the input `data` is a Pandas dataframe and `account` is just a string.

Now I want to run this function in parallel. For this, I create a list with tuples as input data and looks like:

```
input_data = [(account_nr1, df1), (account_nr2, df2), (account_nr2, df2), ...]
```

Next, I use RDD to run the function `calculation` in parallel for many different `account_nr` and `df` (which are Pandas dataframes) combinations. My code for this looks like:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(input_data)
result_rdd = rdd.map(lambda args: calculation(args[0], args[1]))
results = result_rdd.collect()
```

However, I keep getting the error message `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

Does anyone know what this error message means and how I should change my code such that I can run my function in parallel with different input arguments?

Comment: Check data schema and map function

Comment: You cannot create data frame using `spark` in worker nodes.

Comment: @JayashankarGS how should I then parallelise my code in order for my function to run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Notebook').getOrCreate()

def calculation(account: str, data: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    return data

input_data_spark = [(account, spark.createDataFrame(df)) for account, df in input_data]

rdd = sc.parallelize(input_data_spark)

result_rdd = rdd.map(lambda args: calculation(args[0], args[1]))
results = result_rdd.collect()
```

Comment: this again returns this error message: `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.` In this line of code: `rdd = sc.parallelize(input_data_spark)`